# How to copy SDL_Texture struct?

Tags: c++, textures, sdl

I want to create a copy of `texture`like this:

```
SDL_Texture *copy = new SDL_Texture;
*copy = *texture;
```

but I get "Incomplete type is not allowed" error

Comment: Nope. Note a dupe, but it does explain why you can't do what you are doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897076/sdl-texture-incomplete-type

Comment: SDL_Texture is supposed to be an opaque type, so your code can only manipulate it as a pointer and through SDL's functions.  To copy a texture, you need to call SDL functions to set it up the same way.  You will need to copy the pixel data with SDL_LockTexture(), SDL_UpdateTexture(), or by making the new texture a render target and then SDL_RenderCopy() the data (be mindful of the blend mode).